# Sending Requests from react-redux to backend API

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

My back-end server is NodeJs connect to MongoDB atlas, there's a route called **companyorders** which accepts post requests to enable users to create company orders.
I'm trying to send the post request from react application through Redux.

Here's my code...

**Redux Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  initialState,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

export default store;
```

**Redux Actions**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { GET_ERRORS, ADD_COMPANY_ORDER } from './types';

// Add Company Order
export const addCompanyOrder = (orderData) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post('/api/companyorder/create', orderData)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: ADD_COMPANY_ORDER,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      })
    );
};
```

**Redux Reducers**

```
import { ADD_COMPANY_ORDER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {};

export default function addCompanyOrder(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COMPANY_ORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        initialState: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Redux Combined Reducers**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import addCompanyOrder from './companyOrderReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  co_order: addCompanyOrder,
});
```

**The react component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { addCompanyOrder } from '../../actions/companyOrderActions';
class Companyorder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orderName: '',
      date: '',
      orderQuantity: '',
      orderSupplier: '',
      orderCost: '',
      oderTax: '',
      supplierInfo: [
        {
          name: '',
          location: '',
          phone: '',
          email: '',
        },
      ],
      oderReceived: '',
      errors: {},
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: nextProps.errors });
    }
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newOrder = {
      orderName: this.state.orderName,
      date: this.state.date,
      orderQuantity: this.state.orderQuantity,
      orderSupplier: this.state.orderSupplier,
      orderCost: this.state.orderCost,
      oderTax: this.state.oderTax,
      name: this.state.name,
      location: this.state.location,
      phone: this.state.phone,
      email: this.state.email,
    };

    this.props.addCompanyOrder(newOrder);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-link">
              <i className="fas fa-arrow-circle-left" /> Back To Dashboard
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header"> Company Order Form</div>
          <div className="card-body">
            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="orderName" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Name
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="orderName"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.orderName}
                  error={errors.orderName}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="date" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Date
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="date"
                  name="date"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.date}
                  error={errors.date}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="orderQuantity" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Quantity
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="number"
                  name="orderQuantity"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.orderQuantity}
                  error={errors.orderQuantity}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="orderSupplier" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Supplier
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="orderSupplier"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.orderSupplier}
                  error={errors.orderSupplier}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="orderCost" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Cost
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="orderCost"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.orderCost}
                  error={errors.orderCost}
                />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group row">
              <label htmlFor="oderTax" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                Order Tax
              </label>
              <div className="col-10">
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  name="oderTax"
                  minLength="2"
                  required
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                  value={this.state.oderTax}
                  error={errors.orderTax}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-header">
              <h5>Supplier info</h5>
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label htmlFor="name" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                    Name
                  </label>
                  <div className="col-10">
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      minLength="2"
                      required
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={this.state.name}
                      error={errors.name}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label htmlFor="location" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                    Location
                  </label>
                  <div className="col-10">
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="location"
                      minLength="2"
                      required
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={this.state.location}
                      error={errors.loaction}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label htmlFor="phone" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                    Phone
                  </label>
                  <div className="col-10">
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="phone"
                      minLength="2"
                      required
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={this.state.phone}
                      error={errors.phone}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group row">
                  <label htmlFor="email" className="col-2 col-form-label">
                    Email
                  </label>
                  <div className="col-10">
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      type="text"
                      name="email"
                      minLength="2"
                      required
                      onChange={this.onChange}
                      value={this.state.email}
                      error={errors.email}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Submit"
              className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Companyorder.propTypes = {
  addCompanyOrder: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  co_order: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  co_order: state.co_order,
  errors: state.errors,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { addCompanyOrder })(
  withRouter(Companyorder)
);
```

The code is compiling successfully, but redux is not making any request, even not filling the redux state.
If know the error or a better way to do it, please leave your reply and I'm very appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not calling your `onSubmit` handler anywhere in your code.
You should probably wrap your form with a `form` tag and set the onSubmit prop to your handler function.

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
...
</form>
```

By the way, it doesn't seem like your reducer is correct. It seems to me that you probably want something more similar to this:

```
import { ADD_COMPANY_ORDER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
 co_orders: []
};

export default function addCompanyOrder(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_COMPANY_ORDER:
      const newCoOrder = action.payload;

      return {
        co_orders: [...state.co_orders, newCoOrder];
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Other unrelated tips if your app increases in complexity:

- Look into using some sort of immutability library, such as [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) or [ImmutableJS](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) (I would go for the first one). Ref.: https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-immutablejs-with-redux/#using-immutablejs-with-redux
- Look into writing selectors for getting data out of your redux state, and maybe use [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) library. Ref.: https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data/
- Look into using a form library if you have many forms in your app, it will make your life easier ([Formik](https://formik.org/), [react-final-form](https://final-form.org/react) or [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/), among others)